# java.io.IOException: Job failed

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, tomcat6, nutch

I'm trying to index a site with "Apache Nutch 1.4" and when I run the command below, the following error occurs "java.io.IOException: Job failed"

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

I installed "Tomca6" and "Apache Solr 3.5.0" to work with Nutch but unfortunately is not working

**simulation**

```csh
root@debian:/usr/share/nutch/runtime/local$ bin/nutch solrindex     http://localhost:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
SolrIndexer: starting at 2012-03-28 18:45:25
Adding 48 documents
java.io.IOException: Job failed!
root@debian:/usr/share/nutch/runtime/local$
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Do you have a log file somewhere with the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I put a piece of log on the following link for you to see ... [Hadoop.log](https://raw.github.com/gist/2231654/564d7bf5a59262ee9bd63f5a6434e68d822156fb/hadoop.log)

Comment: @Agutoli I'd suggest you to have a look at your solr log file in order to understand the reason of the BadRequest error you get from Solr. Can you paste here the relevant part of it?

Comment: The only log I found is this, does not log the stack trace Solr [Haddop.log](https://raw.github.com/gist/2231654/564d7bf5a59262ee9bd63f5a6434e68d822156fb/hadoop.log)

Answer (score 0):

This error often occurs if the mapping of nutch result fields onto Solr field is incorrect or incomplete. This results in the "update" action being rejected by the Solr server. Unfortunately, at some point in the call chain this error is converted into a "IO error" which is a little misleading. My recommendation is to access the web console of the Solr server (which is accessible using the same URL as for the submissing of links, e.g. in this case http://some.solr.server:8983/solr/) and go to to the logging tab. Errors concerning the mapping will show up there!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Solr is not configured right. (Please ensure that the input linkdb, crawldb and segments are present in the location that you pass command line).

Read

- [Setting up Solr 1.4 with Apache Tomcat 6.X](http://www.params.me/2011/07/apache-solr-14-set-up.html)
- [Nutch 1.3 and Solr Integration](http://www.params.me/2011/07/nutch-13-and-solr-integration.html) .